# Find if list is sequential and with timestamp to today

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Using Entity Framework Core 6 I have the entity:

```
public class Node {
  public String Parameter { get; set; }
  public String Period { get; set; }
  public Decimal Value { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The Period value can be:

```
M1 = 1 Minute
H1 = 1 Hour
D1 = 1 Day
```

For each pair (Parameter, Period) I need to find if I have the most recent 200 values.

For example, I need to find if I have the temperature for the previous 200 days:

```
Parameter = Temperature
Period = D1
```

I need to check all the pairs that don't satisfy this condition. I started with:

```
 var stored = _context.Nodes
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Parameter, x.Period })
  .Select(x => new { 
     Parameter = x.Key.Parameter, 
     Period = x.Key.Period, 
     Count = x.Count() 
  });
```

With this I have the count for each pair.

But I am not sure if they are sequential and reaching today.

Comment: If you need to do that effective, you have to use SQL Window Functions, which are not supported by EF Core, but supported by third party extensions.